# How to implement NetInfo to check network connectivity across different screens?

Tags: react-native, react-native-community-netinfo

I have attached a snipped of a component called `ConnectionChecker` which I have wrapped around all the screen navigations. I have used `NetInfo` to check for the internet connectivity in the Connection Checker component, checking the connection for all the screens. But the network connectivity is not updated even though I used *NetInfo.addEventListner* for the same. The following is working for only one screen. But when I wrap the component around the Drawer Stack, it doesn't update the `NetInfo` variable correctly through which I am checking the network connection.

```js
import NetInfo, { useNetInfo } from '@react-native-community/netinfo';
import React from 'react';

import NoInternetScreen from './NoInternetScreen';

const ConnectionChecker = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
    const netInfo = useNetInfo();

    console.log('NetInfo is: ', netInfo.isConnected);
    console.log('NetInfo type: ', netInfo.type);

    return netInfo.isConnected ? (
        children
    ) : (
        <>
            <NoInternetScreen />
        </>
    );
};

export default ConnectionChecker;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create external function to use everywhere like below;

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

export function isConnected() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
            console.log("Connection type", state.type);
            console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);

            if (state.isConnected) {
                resolve();
            }
            else {
                reject();
            }
        });
    })
}
```

then, you can call this like this:

```
isConnected()
        .then(() => console.log("has internet connection"))
        .catch(() => console.log("no connection"))
```

so, you can import the connection check method to the required screens, components.

Comment: Thanks. I have swtiched my approach by useNetInfo hook. This is my code

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please check what's wrong with it ?

Comment: your approach is correct but not for netInfo. netInfo library is async, so cannot use it like sync library. probably the library then is not called for first time that you try to use. it may return false immediately.
NetInfo.fetch()
        .then(state => {})
        .catch(() => {})

you should update your state inside then.